# Product of $L^2$-norms

Tags: filters, norm

Let $H(e^{j\omega})$ represent the frequency domain response of a minimum phase filter such that $H(e^{j\omega})^{-1}$ exists. Is there a closed-form expression or a bound for the following expression?

$$
\left\lVert H \right\rVert_2^2 \left\lVert \frac{1}{H} \right\rVert_2 ^2
$$

**EDIT:**

$L^2$-norm is defined as a summation over all frequencies. Obviously, the lower bound will be 1 (if averaging), and equality holds if and only if $H(e^{j\omega})=\text{constant}$. But is there a better bound for a general filter response?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say $|| H ||_2^2$, do you mean the integrated L2 norm over all frequencies, or at a point?

Comment: Sorry, should have made it more clear. I meant over all frequencies.

Comment: I thought you did, 'cuz the answer at a point frequency is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

> But is there a better bound for a general filter response?

No. The argument about it $H$ being a minimum phase filter doesn't make a difference. In essence you are asking a math question on some bound for

$$L = \sum X^2 \cdot \sum \frac{1}{X^2}$$

There is none. Let's assume a very simple signal $x = [a,1]$ . The product of the norms is

$$L = (a^2+1)(1/a^2+1) = a^2 + 2 + 1/a^2.$$

It's clear that $L >=4$ and the equation is easily solvable for $a$ for any given value of $L$. In other words: by choosing $a$ you can make $L$ as large as you want it to be, so there is upper bound.